# Spark with Kafka streaming save to Elastic search slow performance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I have a list of data, the value is basically a bson document (think json),  each json ranges from 5k to 20k in size. It either can be in bson object format or can be converted to json directly:

```
Key, Value
--------
K1, JSON1
K1, JSON2
K2, JSON3
K2, JSON4
```

I expect the groupByKey would produce:

```
K1, (JSON1, JSON2)
K2, (JSON3, JSON4)
```

so that when I do:

```
val data = [...].map(x => (x.Key, x.Value))
val groupedData = data.groupByKey()
groupedData.foreachRDD { rdd =>
   //the elements in the rdd here are not really grouped by the Key
}
```

I am so confused the the behaviour of the RDD. I read many articles in the internet including the official website from Spark: https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/scala-programming-guide.html

Still couldn't achieve what I want.

**-------- UPDATED ---------------------**

Basically I really need it to be grouped by the key, the key is the index to be used in Elasticsearch, so that I can perform batch process based on the key via Elasticsearch for Hadoop:

```
EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd);
```

I can't do per partition because Elasticsearch only accept RDD. I tried to use sc.MakeRDD or sc.parallize, both telling me it is not serializable.

I tried to use:

```
EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd, Map(
          "es.resource.write" -> "{TheKeyFromTheObjectAbove}",
          "es.batch.size.bytes" -> "5000000")
```

Documentation of the config is here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html

But it is VERY slow comparing to not using the configuration to define dynamic index based on the value of individual document, I suspect it is parsing every json to fetch the value dynamically.

Comment: check the below example, you can understand better.

Comment: ES is not optimized for many small inserts. If it possible try to  temporary turn off indexing in ES, save data and turn on index again. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Test extends App {

  val session: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder.appName("Example")
    .config(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
    .getOrCreate()
  val sc = session.sparkContext

  import session.implicits._

  case class Message(key: String, value: String)

  val input: Seq[Message] =
    Seq(Message("K1", "foo1"),
      Message("K1", "foo2"),
      Message("K2", "foo3"),
      Message("K2", "foo4"))

  val inputRdd: RDD[Message] = sc.parallelize(input)

  val intermediate: RDD[(String, String)] =
    inputRdd.map(x => (x.key, x.value))
  intermediate.toDF().show()
  //  +---+----+
  //  | _1|  _2|
  //  +---+----+
  //  | K1|foo1|
  //  | K1|foo2|
  //  | K2|foo3|
  //  | K2|foo4|
  //  +---+----+

  val output: RDD[(String, List[String])] =
    intermediate.groupByKey().map(x => (x._1, x._2.toList))
  output.toDF().show()
  //  +---+------------+
  //  | _1|          _2|
  //  +---+------------+
  //  | K1|[foo1, foo2]|
  //  | K2|[foo3, foo4]|
  //  +---+------------+

  output.foreachPartition(rdd => if (rdd.nonEmpty) {
    println(rdd.toList)
  })
  //  List((K1,List(foo1, foo2)))
  //  List((K2,List(foo3, foo4)))

}
```

Comment: Ok, so I need to do foreachPartition. I have additional question regarding Elasticsearch, I can't do per partition because Elasticsearch only accept RDD. I tried to use sc.MakeRDD or sc.parallize, both telling me it is not serializable. Please see my original question. thanks.

Comment: what is your batch input and and what you are trying to do over the list of value which is groupedBy key?

Comment: I've updated the original question with more details. Thanks!